# How to convert from character positions to byte postions in UTF-8 file?

Tags: java, utf-8, byte

I have UTF-8 encoded text file. I can read it by chars. Each char can be either one byte or multibyte. How can I know where one byte was readen and whet it was readen more than one byte?

Answer (score 0):

Count the bytes while reading the `char`s.

For each `char c`:

```
if(c<128)
  bytesCount++;
else if (c<2048)
  bytesCount+=2;
else
  bytesCount+=3;
```

See also encodeing definition [wikipedia URF8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description)

Comment: Adding 2 or 3 for greater character numbers isn't sufficient.  UTF-8 code sequences can be up to 6 bytes long (and produce multiple Java `char` values for a single abstract character), and low-numbered characters *can* be expressed with long byte sequences instead of the usual short ones.

Comment: @Wyzard: Your comment is absolutely correct, aside of the fact that UTF-8 code sequences can be up to 4 bytes long. Quoting [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8): _In November 2003 UTF-8 was restricted by RFC 3629 to end at `U+10FFFF`, in order to match the constraints of the UTF-16 character encoding. This removed all 5- and 6-byte sequences, and about half of the 4-byte sequences._

Comment: That's right but not for character values up to 65535 and only this are supported by java [but feel free to implement up to 6 byte encoding (see wikipedia-link)]